# Selecting data from a column that contains data from a separate column

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm using SQL PLUS.

I have a table with two columns, SERIALNUMBER, and ITEMNUMBER.

I'm trying to find cases where ITEMNUMBER inludes SERIALNUMBER, but also has 00 on the front of the data.

Ex: I have SERIALNUMBER 1234567 and ITEMNUMBER 001234567, I'm trying to find cases where ITEMNUMBER includes SERIALNUMBER but also has 00 on the front. Obviously I have other cases where SERIALNUMBER and ITEMNUMBER match exactly, which is what I am trying to accomplish by finding those that don't and changing them.

I had something like this to find a few examples:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from TABLE WHERE ITEMNUMBER LIKE '%00%';
```

This gave me a good amount of meters that have 00's in them, but that's not necessarily what I want here.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick & dirty option might be using `INSTR`:

```
select * from test
where instr(itemnumber, serialnumber) > 0  -- ITEMNUMBER contains SERIALNUMBER ...
  and itemnumber like '00%';               -- ... and ITEMNUMBER begins with 00
```

Comment: That did exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the commented out portion explaining each line.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `LIKE '%00%'` which will find the 00's in any position. To find it at the start, you need to set it to `LIKE '00%'` with the percent being only at the end of your value.

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
select count(*) from table where regexp_like(itemnumber,'^(00)('||serialnumber||')$');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table Where ItemNumber = '00'+SerialNumber
```

will give you all the records where the itemnumber is the serialnumber with 2 zeros in front of it.  Is that what you are looking for?

Eventually you could update that by:

```
UPDATE Table SET ItemNumber = SerialNumber where ItemNumber = '00'+SerialNumber
```